# Does Flash 5.5 and Flex 4.5 really acceptable for iPhone Apps at App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, flash, apache-flex

My Flex person claims that now Flex can do for iPhone as well. Whereas my iPhone person says Apps done in windows environment cannot be acceptable by App Store. Does anyone expert in both can tell me real thing. If you can share some link on App Store developed in Flex will be really appreciated.

Thank you for all who are reading this

Raja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.  If you are developing your Flash or Flex application for Air Mobile, you can build it for iOS and sell it in the App Store.  Your "iPhone person" is misinformed.  The reason this is possible is because the application is re-packaged as a native application with Objective-C bytecode.  You don't need XCode.  You don't even need a Mac.

You can try it yourself:

1. Download and install the [demo of Flash Builder 4.5](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder)
2. Create a [new Mobile Flex application](http://www.screencast.com/t/EPLk2RfSD2).
3. [Select iOS as a target platform.](http://www.screencast.com/t/EZENuQyOPb)  Android is also an option
4. Develop your app
5. You have the choice to [run the app in an emulator](http://www.screencast.com/t/uhqEAHA7c7) or [build it as an iOS package](http://www.screencast.com/t/rvqudqqvnYq)
6. If you build it to run on iOS, you will need to use iTunes to load it.  [Provisioning rules](http://www.screencast.com/t/w8bXWUt7oWUn) (including being a member of the Apple Developer Network) apply the same as normal iOS development.

Good luck!

Comment: +1.  However, isn't it true you need OSX to actually submit your finished IPA to the Apple App store?  In most cases that is a Mac, but I understand OSX running on virtualization or a "Hackintosh" will also suffice.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Ah, you are correct.  The last step of submission, "The Application Loader", is only available on OSX.  Every other step of development can be done in Windows, but the last inch has to be OSX.  Sneaky bastards :)  More info here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/app_store_guide.html

Comment: @BrianGenisio thanks Brian, can you please tell what actually is the application loader? And does that mean that we must have atleast one OSX to do this last step always?

Answer (score 1):

Packaged in AIR, Flash / Flex based apps have been accepted to the App Store.

**Flex:**

PolitiFact
http://gregsramblings.com/2011/06/28/adobe-flex-app-is-the-1-news-app-in-itunes-app-store/

http://gregsramblings.com/2011/08/09/politifact-app-now-in-5-mobile-app-stores-one-flex-project/

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplatform/2011/06/adobe-flash-builder-flex-app-politifact-named-1-for-news-in-itunes.html

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/politifact-mobile/id444548650?mt=8

**Flash:**

Machinarium by Amanita Design

http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20104108-264/flash-derived-ipad-game-tops-app-store-charts/

http://thenextweb.com/apple/2011/09/09/the-best-selling-ipad-app-on-the-app-store-was-created-with-adobe-flash/

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/machinarium/id459189186?mt=8